# Jquery Sortable Conflict in jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, tabs

I have added Jquery sortable on each jquery tabs.

Sortable working file in first tabs, reset of the tabs meets conflict with first tabs sorting. (i mean when i sorting the second tabs box that will affect first tabs also).
You can check the error by make all tabs "display:block" with firebug.

[DEMO Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/v3a4jtqp/2/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".drag_wrapper").sortable({
            containment: ".drag_wrapper"
        }).disableSelection();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
        $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
    });
</script>
```

containment:".drag_wrapper" option is necessary for some reason.